# Corrupt RTF, can't view the pictures

Tags: rtf

Basically a rtf document of mine somehow got corrupt, and all the pictures in it is now replaced by blank placeholders. Is there anything I can do to extract the pictures? I made it using LibreOffice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try opening and saving the corrupted file in wordpad.

In linux,once wine installed, using the command

```
      wine wordpad
```

i have managed to open the corrupted file properly and retrieve it.